# I do not get an error on the client-side during tls-handshake

Tags: go, ssl, mtls

I am trying around with mTls and go. I do not really understand how I got tls errors during the handshake on the client side.
See the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

const CRT = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nM+GhLnsX+JNAU2e8E9cxCcceC8IaPAbX8y1teGCt9ukIxhE=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
const KEY = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nVOObYItn69ougXDjKwHR9t/q02fLVMmUAYBKEqaVWErMzJnssrQ=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

const PORT = 1555

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    startServer()

    config := &tls.Config{
        RootCAs: x509.NewCertPool(),
    }
    config.RootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(CRT))

    con, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:"+strconv.Itoa(1555), config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("I do not have a client cert, I should reach here")
        panic(err)
    }
    defer con.Close()

    n, err := con.Write([]byte("msg"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("At least here should be a error")
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Wrote %d bytes\n", n)
    wg.Wait()

}

func startServer() {
    wg.Add(1)
    cert, _ := tls.X509KeyPair([]byte(CRT), []byte(KEY))
    config := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        ClientAuth:   tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
        ClientCAs:    x509.NewCertPool(),
    }
    config.ClientCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(CRT))

    socket, _ := tls.Listen("tcp", ":"+strconv.Itoa(PORT), config)
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer socket.Close()
        conn, _ := socket.Accept()

        n, _ := conn.Read(buffer)
        fmt.Println(string(buffer[:n]))
        conn.Close()

    }()
}
```

The Server is configured with `RequireAndVerifyClientCert`. If you run this example you will also see that on the server side the string `msg` is not printed. This I am expecting since I do not send a client certificate. But the client says the message was transmitted successful.

The strange part is, I would expect that a I got an error during the `tls.Dial` call on the client side. But maybe this is just the tcp connection and tls will be done later.
But the really strange part is, that i can call the write function and this does not return an error and even returns `n=3` indecating that the server received 3 bytes.

Note: If you change  `RequireAndVerifyClientCert` to `NoClientCert` the server part will correctly receive the message.

Why does go not tell me that the tls handshake has failed? Or does it really not fail (What am I doing wrong)?

Comment: There is no error checking on the server-side (unless this was left out for brevity). FYI... you will not see an error on Dial - this only opens a connection, it does not send any bytes - and thus the `TLS` layer has not kicked in yet.

Comment: Yes, I ignore all errors on the server side for this example for simplicity. I also notice the Handschake function on the client sind that should trigger tls handschake ? But also this gives me not an error…

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot more. I think it is either a bug or some sort of intentional.

I ask the question in the go project. -> https://github.com/golang/go/issues/59012